# Javascript calling object function from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

Main:

```
var array = [];
array.push(new npc(mapname, maps));
array.push(new npc(mapname, maps));
console.log("first id: " + array[0].getID());
console.log("second id: " + array[1].getID());
```

Npc.js:

```
var id;
function npc(mapname, maps) {
    id = maps[mapname].npcs.length + 1;
    console.log("ID set to: " + id);
    maps[mapname].npcs.push(this);
}
Npc.prototype.getID = function() {
    return id;
};
```

Output:

```
ID set to: 1
ID set to: 2
first id: 2
second id: 2
```

I can't get my head around why the output is 2,2 rather than 1,2. No matter which way I set it up I get the same results.

Is it something to do with only one occurrence of `var id` be accessed by two instances of the same class or do I have to push a copy to the array?

Either way I don't know why it happens or how to resolve this issue.

Comment: id does in fact have scope across the two npc objects you create.

Comment: I guess you need to bone up on `this` and how it's used to hold instance-specific values.

Comment: Maybe, I didn't realise I removed the 'this' when trying to fix another error cause initially it was fine. I've been looking at it for so long the simplest most basic things are the hardest to pick out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared `id` as a global variable rather than an instance variable. The second time you call `new npc` you overwrite the global `id` variable, which is why `array[1].getID()` returns the wrong value.

```
id = maps[mapname].npcs.length + 1
```

should really be

```
this.id = maps[mapname].npcs.length + 1
```

and

```
Npc.prototype.getID = function() {
    return id;
};
```

should really be

```
Npc.prototype.getID = function() {
    return this.id;
};
```

Comment: Of course it was something so simple. Feeling a bit silly, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are setting ID here:

```
id = maps[mapname].npcs.length + 1;
```

And you are defining it as global var (at the top of your statement) so ultimately you are saying, okay ID=1, then now set the ID=2... then you ask what is ID?  It was most recently set to two, so both responses will be 2.

If you did console.log between your two pushes it would work...

You need to make the id live as a property of your object instead of a global variable.